# Android studio error- could not resolve resource @string/desc

Tags: android

I was trying to build a simple splash screen on Android Studio but got this error:

> "No resource found that matches the given name(at `contentDescription` with value `@string/desc`)".

this is my colors.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
 <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
 <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
 <drawable name="splash" />
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have an element in `string.xml` to match your reference.

Navigate to `res` -> `values` folder, open or create `strings.xml` and add something like this:

```
 <string name="desc">A description</string>
```

See how the attribute `name="desc"` matches `@string/desc`?

Comment: Thank you sam your solution worked but still have a little error 'string types not allowed at splash with value'.

Comment: Use the Edit button under your question to post your XML file.  I can only guess that your are using `@string...` incorrectly

Comment: i have updated my question and haved added the xml file